# Compare the content of two arrays in swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array that I have to cut, on the first 3, 7 or 30 entries.

Then I have an ArraySlice which I want to pack into an array.

Now if I want to compare the new array I created from the ArraySlice with another array (if both have the same content) I always get false as the result.

I believe it is due to the newly created Array from the ArraySlice.

What can I do so that the result is not always false. the content is the same, have checked it with print (...)

```
extension Date {
    static func compareLastDays (compareArray: [Date]) -> Bool{

        var compareArray2: [Date] = []
        var createDateArray: [Date] = []

        var days = compareArray.count

        if days >= 30 {
            days = 30
            let arraySlice =  compareArray.prefix(days)
            compareArray2 = Array(arraySlice)
        }
        else if days >= 7{
            days = 7
            let arraySlice = compareArray.prefix(days)
            compareArray2 = Array(arraySlice)
        }
        else {
            days = 3
            let arraySlice = compareArray.prefix(days)
            compareArray2 = Array(arraySlice)
        }

        let startDate = Date.init()
        var endDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -days, to: startDate)!

        print("startDate", startDate)
        print("endDate", endDate)


        while startDate > endDate{
            createDateArray.insert(endDate, at: 0)
            guard let newDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: endDate) else {
                break
            }
            print("extension new Date", newDate)
            endDate = newDate
        }
        print(compareArray2, "extension compareArray")
        print(createDateArray, "extension createDateArray")


        if createDateArray == compareArray2 {
            print("Compare ARRAY true", createDateArray, compareArray2)
            return true
        }
        else {
            print("Compare ARRAY false", createDateArray, compareArray2)
            return false
        }

    }
}
```

print statements:

```
    startDate 2019-07-28 19:00:22 +0000 
    endDate 2019-07-21 19:00:22 +0000 
    extension new Date 2019-07-22 19:00:22 +0000 
    extension new Date 2019-07-23 19:00:22 +0000
    extension new Date 2019-07-24 19:00:22 +0000 
    extension new Date 2019-07-25 19:00:22 +0000 
    extension new Date 2019-07-26 19:00:22 +0000 
    extension new Date 2019-07-27 19:00:22 +0000 
    extension new Date 2019-07-28 19:00:22 +0000 

[2019-07-27 19:00:22 +0000, 2019-07-26 19:00:22 +0000, 2019-07-25 19:00:22 +0000, 2019-07-24 19:00:22 +0000, 2019-07-23 19:00:22 +0000, 2019-07-22 19:00:22 +0000, 2019-07-21 19:00:22 +0000] extension compareArray 
[2019-07-27 19:00:22 +0000, 2019-07-26 19:00:22 +0000, 2019-07-25 19:00:22 +0000, 2019-07-24 19:00:22 +0000, 2019-07-23 19:00:22 +0000, 2019-07-22 19:00:22 +0000, 2019-07-21 19:00:22 +0000] extension createDateArray 
Compare ARRAY false [2019-07-27 19:00:22 +0000, 2019-07-26 19:00:22 +0000, 2019-07-25 19:00:22 +0000, 2019-07-24 19:00:22 +0000, 2019-07-23 19:00:22 +0000, 2019-07-22 19:00:22 +0000, 2019-07-21 19:00:22 +0000] [2019-07-27 19:00:22 +0000, 2019-07-26 19:00:22 +0000, 2019-07-25 19:00:22 +0000, 2019-07-24 19:00:22 +0000, 2019-07-23 19:00:22 +0000, 2019-07-22 19:00:22 +0000, 2019-07-21 19:00:22 +0000]
```

Comment: The output of your print statements would be helpful.

Comment: I believe date comparison includes milliseconds which are not visible in your prints. The following prints false: `let now = Date()
let now2 = Date()

print(now == now2 )
`

Comment: What exactly is this all supposed to do? It's called `compareLastDays`, but that doesn't really communicate much, and I'm having hard time reverse engineering it from the code. What exactly is it comparing? Why are `3`, `7` `30` hardcoded?

Comment: I want to check 2 arrays, the array that I pass when calling the function compareLastDays should have either 3, 7 or 10 consecutive days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to solve this is to extract some of the date components for the dates and then compare the components.

The below code will fail when comparing the dates directly but succeed when comparing the components which goes from year down to seconds

```
let now = Date()
let now2 = Date()
print(now == now2 ) // -> false

let components1 = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year,.month,.day,.hour,.minute, .second], from: now)
let components2 = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year,.month,.day,.hour,.minute, .second], from: now2)
print(components1 == components2) // -> true
```

To make the code clearer the set of components can be made into a constant

```
let compareSet:Set<Calendar.Component> = [.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second]
```

A similar solution to this could be to use a DateFormatter and compare the strings. Both offers the possibility to easily set the precision used when comparing dates

Here is a way to do with a DateFormatter but in this example the comparison is only done down to minutes

```
let df = DateFormatter()
df.dateStyle = .full
df.timeStyle = .short
print(df.string(from: now) == df.string(from: now2))
```

*Of course for either solution the arrays can't be compared directly and instead they need to be looped over and each component needs to be compared individually to the component in the other array*

Below is an example using the date formatter solution

```
guard compareArray2.count == createDateArray.count else { return false}
for i in 0..<compareArray2.count {
    if df.string(from: compareArray2[i]) != df.string(from: createDateArray[i]) {
        return false
    }
}
return true
```

Comment: What if you compare the last millisecond of one second with the first millisecond of the next second?

Comment: @matt Ah, you mean this doesn't handle rounding? I guess for that one need to include one more component than what's used in the comparison and manually adjust the next smallest value.

Comment: So it is completely wrong to compare date components from two dates? Is it equally wrong to compare the dates converted to strings?

Comment: I didn’t say that. I say the answer doesn’t solve the problem. If you think the issue is that two dates very close to each other should be considered equal, you should be comparing them by an epsilon difference.

Comment: @matt Ok I understand what you say now. What I meant but didn't explicitly say was that that it was up to OP to determine what equal means for this use case by only including "enough" components

Comment: @NewYorker A comment like that makes it impossible for me to try to improve my answer

Comment: I'm sorry. so if I try it like this: let components1 = Calendar.current.dateComponents ([. year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: createDateArray) I get an error:

Can not convert value of type '[Date]' to expected argument type 'Date'

Comment: @NewYorker You can't use it on the whole array, you need to do it for each date in the array

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Your last function can be much more example implemented as `createDateArray.elementsEqual(compareArray2, by: { df.string(from: $0) == df.string(from: $1) })`

Answer (score 0):

since the code is tricky and you said it doesn't work which it should, i found you this work around:

```
extension Array where Element: Hashable {
    func isSame(from other: [Element]) -> Bool {
        let thisSet = Set(self)
        let otherSet = Set(other)
        let arr = Array(thisSet.symmetricDifference(otherSet))

        if arr.count == 0{
            return true
        }else{
            return false
        }
    }
}

let date1 = Date()
let date2 = Date()
let date3 = Date()
let arr1 = [date1,date2,date3]
let arr2 = [date1,date2]

arr1.isSame(from: arr2)
```

if the 2 arrays are the same, it return true, else false.

Comment: @sci3nt15t `isSame(from:)` is a really misleading name. For one, it doesn't make it clear "how" it "the same", and why it's any different from `==`. Also, this disregards duplicates, so `[a]` and `[a, a]` are "the same", which is entirely non-obvious. A better name would be something like `hasSameElementsIgnoringCount(as other: [Element]) -> Bool`